# How to create a @mixin for CSS dropshadow

Tags: css, sass, scss-mixins

I am having trouble creating a `@mixin` for a drop shadow. The drop shadow I want in regular CSS is as follows

```
-webkit-box-shadow: 0px 2px 3px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
-moz-box-shadow: 0px 2px 3px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
box-shadow: 0px 2px 3px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
```

The `@mixin` I have created is as such

```
@mixin box-shadow(
    $top, $left, $blur, $size, $color) {
}
```

Then to use this I have added the below to my scss file

```
@include box-shadow(0, 2px, 3px, 2px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2));
```

However, it is broken as I do not see any drop shadow CSS being applied once the SCSS is compiled.

Comment: Hi, can you provide us with the resulting CSS file ?

Answer (score 6):

Try this: [**Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/fybuv82s/1/)

```
@mixin box-shadow($top, $left, $blur, $size, $color) {
   -webkit-box-shadow: $top $left $blur $size $color;
   -moz-box-shadow: $top $left $blur $size $color;
   box-shadow: $top $left $blur $size $color;
}

.box{
  width:150px;
  height:150px;
  background:blue;
  @include box-shadow(2px,2px,5px,0, rgba(0,0,0,0.6));
}
```

Comment: This answer worked for me. Thank you to you and everyone who helped :)

Comment: Accept helpful answer. Just click green sign below up and down vote.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you've left out declaring the `box-shadow` rules in your mixin.

It should look like this:

```
@mixin box-shadow($top, $left, $blur, $size, $color) {
  box-shadow: $top $left $blur $size $color
}
```

Add the vendor prefixes as you need.

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1s6fktq9/)

Answer (score 0):

I use this

```
/* BOXSHADOW */
@mixin boxshadow(@x: 0, @y: 0, @blur: 0, @spread: 0, @rgba: rgba(0, 0, 0, 1.0)) {
  -webkit-box-shadow: @x*@rem @y*@rem @blur*@rem @spread*@rem @rgba;
  -moz-box-shadow:    @x*@rem @y*@rem @blur*@rem @spread*@rem @rgba;
  box-shadow:         @x*@rem @y*@rem @blur*@rem @spread*@rem @rgba;
}

@include boxshadow(0, 0, 10, -5, rgba(220, 220, 220, 1.0));
```

Comment: Ekks .. Thank you but this seems to break real bad :(

Answer (score 0):

You could try to use [Compass](http://compass-style.org/). It provides a lot of mixins for the most common CSS rules, including *box-shadow*. It also transparently add cross-browser prefixes while using its mixins.